# How is destructor called for temporary objects returned from a function in C++?

Tags: c++, raii

Here's a code from Stroustrup's "The C++ Programming Language" that implements a `finally` which I cannot quiet understand where the destructor gets called.

```
template<typename F> struct Final_action
{
  Final_action(F f): clean{f} {}
  ~Final_action() { clean(); }
  F clean;
}

template<class F> 
Final_action<F> finally(F f)
{
  return Final_action<F>(f);
}

void test(){
  int* p=new int{7};
  auto act1 = finally( [&]{delete p;cout<<"Goodbye,cruel world\n";} );
}
```

I have two questions around this:

1. According to the author, the `delete p` only gets called once: when act1 goes out of scope. But from my understanding: first, `act1` will be initialized with the copy constructor, then the temporary object `Final_action<F>(f)` in the function `finally` gets destructed, calling `delete p` for the first time, then a second time at the end of the function `test` when `act1` is out of scope. Where am I getting it wrong?
2. Why is the `finally` function needed? Can't I just define `Final_action act1([&]{delete p;cout<<"Goodbye,cruel world\n"})`? Is that the same?

Also, if anyone can think of a better title, please modify the current one.

UPDATE: After some further thinking, I'm now convinced that the destructor may be called thrice. The additional one is for the temporary objected auto-generated in the calling function `void test()` used as the argument to the copy constructor of `act1`. This can be verified with `-fno-elide-constructors` option in g++. For those who have the same question as me, see [Copy elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) as well as [Return value optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) as pointed out in the answer by Bill Lynch.

Comment: One question per question, please.

Comment: re #2 I don't see why not. I guess someone obsessed with `auto` thought this was easier to read.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Template argument deduction. You can't actually write the type of the `Final_action<???>` because of the lambda.

Comment: @Quentin: Haha oh yeah

Comment: Read the chapter again. The copy constructor and the `operator=` are both set to delete to prevent `Final_action` from being copied. Furthermore your example code misses at least one semicolon after the `cout`

Comment: @Quentin Does lambda have a type? Is it the same type as a function pointer? Maybe a silly question, I'm a novice :D

Comment: Update: [This](https://books.google.de/books?id=kCF4BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA358&dq=struct+Final_action&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAmoVChMIztbthqT-xwIVpg9yCh213QFD#v=onepage&q=struct%20Final_action&f=false) vs [This](https://books.google.de/books?id=PSUNAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA358&dq=struct+Final_action&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAWoVChMIztbthqT-xwIVpg9yCh213QFD#v=onepage&q=struct%20Final_action&f=false)

Comment: @btshengsheng a lambda-expression creates a function object (functor), of a type that is generated by the compiler. The type's name is unknown to the programmer, but apart from that it's a regular class with an `operator ()`.

Comment: @btshengsheng
re #2 You can do it, but it will be very monstrous: 

    Final_action<std::function<void()> > act1([&](){ delete p; cout<<"Goodbye,cruel worldv1\n";}); 


and also need include <functional>

Comment: @POTEMKINDX Please don't. Compare [this](http://goo.gl/lm3Tcv) and [this](http://goo.gl/kMSVBE)

Comment: @POTEMKINDX that would be abusing `std::function`.

Answer (score 13):

You are correct, this code is broken. It only works correctly when [return value optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) are applied. This line:

```
auto act1 = finally([&]{delete p;cout<<"Goodbye,cruel world\n"})
```

May or may not invoke the copy constructor. If it does, then you will have two objects of type `Final_action` and you will thus call that lambda twice.

Comment: Probably someone saying "well this is how it works on _my_ system" and not caring enough to write even remotely portable code .. or even code that fails properly :(

Comment: Note : to fix it, make `Final_action` a movable-only type.

Comment: @Quentin: Even easier fix: `auto&&` -- extends the lifetime of the temporary to match `act1`, prevents any copying

Comment: @BenVoigt This would work, but leaves the landmine in the field.

Comment: @Quentin: Well, copy and move operations on `Final_action` should both be deleted, because neither makes sense (a moved-from instance will also blow up, unless that class is totally rewritten).

Comment: Looks like the chapter got an update: [Here](https://books.google.de/books?id=kCF4BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA358&dq=struct+Final_action&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAmoVChMIztbthqT-xwIVpg9yCh213QFD#v=onepage&q=struct%20Final_action&f=false) vs [Here](https://books.google.de/books?id=PSUNAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA358&dq=struct+Final_action&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAWoVChMIztbthqT-xwIVpg9yCh213QFD#v=onepage&q=struct%20Final_action&f=false)

Comment: For #2, which you may want to cover in your answer, you could have `auto deleter = [&] { /* bla bla */ }; Final_action<decltype(deleter)> act1{ deleter};`

Comment: @BenVoigt If both copy and move operations on `Final_action` is deleted, how will the object be returned?

Comment: @SimonKraemer The updated code is incorrect as well, see the answer by Arne Vogel.

Comment: @bsthengsheng I didn't test it, but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5):

Simplest fix is

```
template<typename F> 
struct Final_action
{
  Final_action(F f): clean{std::move(f)} {}
  Final_action(const Final_action&) = delete;
  void operator=(const Final_action&) = delete;
  ~Final_action() { clean(); }
  F clean;
};

template<class F> 
Final_action<F> finally(F f)
{
  return { std::move(f) };
}
```

And use as

```
auto&& act1 = finally( [&]{delete p;cout<<"Goodbye,cruel world\n";} );
```

The use of copy-list-initialization and a lifetime-extending forwarding reference avoid any copy/moving of the `Final_action` object. Copy-list-initialization constructs the temporary `Final_action` return value directly, and the temporary returned by `finally` has its lifetime extended by binding to `act1` - also without any copying or moving.

Comment: Works fine! For those who may wonder, the curly brace in the return statement `return { std::move(f) }` invokes the copy-list-initialization, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return).

Answer (score 3):

The code is broken. The revised code mentioned by SimonKraemer is *also* broken – it doesn't compile (the return statement in `finally` is illegal because `Final_action` is neither copyable nor moveable). Making `Final_action` move-only with generated move constructor also doesn't work because is `F` guaranteed to have a move constructor (if it hasn't, then `Final_action`'s generated move constructor will silently use `F`'s copy constructor as a fallback), nor is `F` guaranteed to be a no-op after the move. In fact, the lambda from the example will *not* turn into a no-op.

There is a relatively easy and portable solution:

Add a flag `bool valid = true;` to `Final_action` and overwrite move c'tor and move assignment to clear the flag *in the source object*. Only invoke `clean()` if `valid`. This prevents the generation of copy c'tor and copy assignment, so they do not need to be explicitly deleted. (Bonus points: Put the flag into a reusable move-only wrapper so that you don't have to implement the move c'tor and move assignment of `Final_action`. You don't need the explicit deletes in this case either.)

Alternatively, remove `Final_action`'s template argument and change it to use `std::function<void()>` instead. Check that `clean` is not empty before invoking it. Add move c'tor and move assignment that set the original `std::function` to `nullptr`. (Yes, this is necessary to be portable. Moving a `std::function` does *not* guarantee that the source will be empty.) Advantage: The usual benefits of type erasure, such as being able to return the scope guard into an outer stack frame without exposing `F`. Disadvantage: may add significant run time overhead.

In my current work project, I basically combined the two approaches with a `ScopeGuard<F>` and an `AnyScopeGuard` using a type erasing function object. The former uses a `boost::optional<F>` and can be converted to the latter. As an added benefit of allowing scope guards to be empty, I can explicitly `dismiss()` them as well. This allows using the scope guard to set up the rollback part of a transaction and then dismissing it upon commit (with non-throwing code).

UPDATE: Stroustrup's new example doesn't even compile. I missed that explicitly deleting the copy c'tor also disables the generation of the move c'tor.

Comment: The revised code by SimonKraemer **indeed** won't compile (I've tested with g++), because as you said, move constructor won't be auto-generated when copy constructor is explicitly declared (as deleted), see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457344.aspx).

Comment: After reading your first paragraph 6 times, I think I finally fully get what you mean :-). I'm assuming you missed a _neither_ on the fourth line of your answer? BTW, It's quite interesting to see Stroustrup producing incorrect code over and over again... Thank you.